# How do define this model in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a json model that looks like this

```
{
    "loggers" : {
        "logger1" : {
            "name" : "logger1",
            "level" : "DEBUG",
            "sub_loggers" :{
                "logger1.nested_logger1" : {
                    "name": "logger1.nested_logger1",
                    "level": "INFO"
                },
                "logger1.nested_logger2" : {
                    "name": "logger1.nested_logger2",
                    "level": "INFO",
                    "sub_loggers": {
                        "logger1.nested_logger2.more_of_that" : {
                            "name": "logger1.nested_logger2.more_of_that",
                            "level": "INFO"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "logger2" : {
            "name": "logger2",
            "level": "WARN"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to save the model as I receive it from a HTTP request in a variable, but I want it to be mapped, so I don't have to use `any`.

If there's a way to separate it into 2 models, I'd want that even more,
I just don't know how to map it because `sub_loggers` is not an array, it's an object who's key names are also the names of the loggers they represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
type Level = "DEBUG" | "INFO" | "WARN" | "ERROR";

type Loggers = {
    [name: string]: Logger;
}

interface Logger {
    name: string;
    level: Level;
    sub_loggers?: Loggers;
}

let json = YOUR_JSON as { loggers: Loggers };
let loggers: Loggers = json["loggers"];
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20GTree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20createNode(name%3A%20string)%3A%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GNodeImpl(name)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GNodeImpl%20implements%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D#src=function%20extend%3CT%3E(list%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D).swap%20%3D%20function%20(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20this%5Bi1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi1%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bi2%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi2%5D%20%3D%20tmp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20extend(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0Alist.swap(0%2C%202)%3B%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B3%2C%202%2C%201%5D#src=class%20CustomError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%60Lorem%20%22%24%7Bmessage%7D%22%20ipsum%20dolor.%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'CustomError'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Athrow%20new%20CustomError('foo')%3B#src=class%20CustomError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%60Lorem%20%22%24%7Bmessage%7D%22%20ipsum%20dolor.%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'CustomError'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Athrow%20new%20CustomError('foo')%3B#src=const%20IGNORE_FIELDS%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20JsonIgnore(cls%3A%20any%2C%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20clsName%20%3D%20cls.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(IGNORE_FIELDS.has(clsName))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20IGNORE_FIELDS.get(clsName)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IGNORE_FIELDS.set(clsName%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20list.push(name)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20toJson()%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20json%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20ignore%20%3D%20IGNORE_FIELDS.get(this.constructor.name)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20ignore.indexOf(name)%20%3C%200).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20json%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bname%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20json%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TblColabAdmin%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20snomatrcompl%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20nflativo%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%40JsonIgnore%0A%20%20%20%20ativo%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(snomatrcompl%3A%20string%2C%20nflativo%3A%20number%2C%20ativo%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.snomatrcompl%20%3D%20snomatrcompl%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.nflativo%20%3D%20nflativo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.ativo%20%3D%20ativo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20new%20TblColabAdmin(%22str%22%2C%2043%2C%20true).toJson()%3B%0Aconsole.log(obj)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Bsnomatrcompl%3A%20%22few%22%2C%20nflativo%3A%2043%7D#src=type%20Level%20%3D%20%22DEBUG%22%20%7C%20%22INFO%22%20%7C%20%22WARN%22%20%7C%20%22ERROR%22%3B%0A%0Atype%20Loggers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Logger%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Logger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20level%3A%20Level%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sub_loggers%3F%3A%20Loggers%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22loggers%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22DEBUG%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sub_loggers%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1.nested_logger1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1.nested_logger1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22INFO%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1.nested_logger2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1.nested_logger2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22INFO%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sub_loggers%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1.nested_logger2.more_of_that%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1.nested_logger2.more_of_that%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22INFO%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22WARN%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20as%20%7B%20loggers%3A%20Loggers%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20loggers%3A%20Loggers%20%3D%20json%5B%22loggers%22%5D%3B))

---

#### Edit

To answer your comment questions:

1. Yes, `?` marks an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties).
2. I haven't used classes at all, I used [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) and [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases).
   The differences between interfaces and type aliases is explained in the linked documentation.
   I haven't used classes because from your question it seemed that you're looking only to represent your json structure so that the compiler will use type safety.
   If you need to have actual instances so that you'll have functionality (methods) and not just having data objects, then you'll need to use classes.

Comment: I have several question: 1) does the `?` indicate optional? 2) why did you declare `Loggers` as `type` and not `class`? But beside of that, thank you so much. This is really helpful!

Comment: Check my revised answer